# In excel, how to find largest letter in a range which also contain some blank cells

Tags: excel-formula

In my excel sheet, I wanted to find the largest letter in a range.
Some cells in the range are blank cells.

I have tried using a code obtained from a website, however it works only when there is no blank cell.

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(D6:L6,">"&D6:L6)=0),D6:L6)
```

No output when some cells in the range are blank cells, i mean not all cells contain letter.

Sample data :

result is "B"

```
B   B   E   B   B   B   B   C
```

result in nothing (because not all 8 cells contain letter, 2 cells are blank).

```
B       E       C   C   B   C
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks but sorry i dont know how to upload a spreadsheet data here

Comment: By "largest letter," do you mean the one that is used the most?

Comment: If there are "A", "B", "C" then the largest letter is "A"

Comment: Do you only have capital letters? Do you ever have more than one letter in a cell?

Comment: Funny, I would have thought C would be the largest letter.  good thing you clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data, you may be able to do something like this, using CHAR, CODE, and AGGREGATE to ignore blank cells:

```
=CHAR(AGGREGATE(15,6,CODE(A1:A10),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Just to tack on to BigBen's answer. Since AGGREGATE performs array like calculations with formula 15, you will want to restrict the range to something close to the number of rows in you data range and avoid full column references such as A:A.